# Issue in Android 4.1 while loading background image

Tags: android, gif, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I am having an Application working fine in all the versions, but in 4.1 the background is looking black. I am using gif file.

Is 4.1 support gif file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `png` files, You can convert `gif` file using paint or other software. Android 4.1 does not support `GIF` files to be set as background.